# redis-cli pipeling, how to finish input?

Tags: redis

According to redis manual (http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert), I do the following from command line (debian):

```
dev@dev:~$ redis-cli --pipe
*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$3\r\nkey\r\n$5\r\nvalue\r\n
```

What is corresponds to
**SET key value**
command for redis-server...

Now, how to "commit" (send) that command to server?
Can't find any ways... It was an examples with text files, but I need to commit manually...

Answer (score 1):

Redis should commit everything automatically unless you're inside a `MULTI` block.

Comment: We are about redis client, not server.. when I type that string & press enter - it just goes on the next line...

Comment: As far as I know, the client just relays that directly to the server using the raw protocol. After each line the statement is committed. If you mean "How do I end my input" then you need to supply a `^D` to tell your shell to stop waiting for more.